# Number of Vapor Particles During Sublimation

Tags: thermodynamics

During sublimation, the solid phase transitions to a gaseous phase. If you were to place this solid inside of a constant volume V at a certain temperature T, the system would reach a steady state. I am wondering how one would find the number of particles in the vapor at a certain temperature.
What I thought would be the solution is to the use the Clausius-Clapeyron equation
$$\frac{dlog_{10}P}{d(1/T)}=-\frac{\Delta H^{sub}}{2.303N_ak_B}$$
which defines the thermodynamics of phase transitions. $N_a$ is avoagodros number, $\Delta H$ is molar enthalpy of the sublimation phase transition, and P is the pressure. Could one simply write the an ideal gas law substituion for P in this case, since I assume that the Pressure that this equation describes is of course for the gaseous phase? In that case, one could obtain the number of particles N from this substitution. However, in doing so, it assumes that the vapor follows the ideal gas law (I think for my case I am fine with this).
Additionally, if this method does work, would using the the Clausius-Clapeyron relation from wikipedia:
$$\frac{dP}{dT}=\frac{TRn}{L}$$
where L is the specific latent heat of the phase transition, work equivalently?
Thank you!

Comment: The sublimating solid has a vapor pressure, and the vapor coming off of that solid will not follow the ideal gas law.  For a liquid, you would use the Antoine equation.  For a solid, some research is required.

Comment: @DavidWhite - if the vapor is simple (one constituent), why would it not be very nearly ideal? True, various solids have multi-component gas phases, but at room temperature even they are pretty ideal.

Comment: @JonCuster for the equilibrium vapor pressure, the vapor is continuously freezing to the solid surface and the solid surface is continually evaporating.  Both rates are equal.  This phenomenon does not match the description of an ideal gas, whose atoms or molecules do not interact with each other.  In addition, when I have calculated this situation for liquids and vapors at equilibrium, I never used the ideal gas law because it doesn't apply.

Comment: @DavidWhite Your argument about evaporation and freezing at the interface is not convincing. More convincing would be the observation that in Clausius-Clapeyron's equation, the right-hand side depends on the properties of both the solid and the vapor phases. While the vapor phase is almost always well described by the perfect gas law, the solid is never.

Comment: Your are all correct, you should find a problem based on this concept and solve it using both equations I can bet results will be same.

Comment: Kinetics of what happens at the solid-vapor interface are completely irrelevant to the thermodynamics of the phase equilibrium.

Comment: @JonCuster OK.  Run through the law of corresponding states (a chemical engineering concept) to determine what the "z" factor is for a condensing or sublimating vapor.  For an ideal gas, it is 1.  For a sublimating gas, I am sure that the "z" factor is not 1 unless the sublimation is taking place at very low pressures.

Comment: Yes, you need the pressure to be low compared to the critical point. For materials that are solid at room temperature that is a good bet. Heck, water vapor is pretty much an ideal gas at normal human environments.